# Define via UIFont(...) or setTitleTextAttributes that a label shows always a lowercase string

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationitem, uifont

I need to force that the back button text in my iOS 8.4 and later app will be always lowercase.

I already use the `AppDelegate` to set some custom appearance. 
E.g.:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([...], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

This works fine. But I cannot find an attribute to say "hey `UINavigationBarItem` please lowercase the back button title".

> "Back" -> "back"

Am I blind or is it not possible to do it that way?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a category from UIViewController and in it use something like  this

`self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = [self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title lowercaseString];`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added it to my custom generic ViewController `viewDidAppear`method, but backBarButton is always `nil`

Comment: It's too early, try to move this code to viewWillAppear

Comment: This does not really help. I'll have a look later this week. Thanks a lot for the tip!

Comment: Try to recreate it ```self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:lowerCaseTitle style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];```